# Android Out of memory exception and ContentResolver.registerContentObserver

Tags: android, memory-management, android-contentresolver, contentobserver

In my activity, I have about 10 `ContentObservers` registered to the `ContentResolver (registerContentObserver)`. I do it in the `onCreate()`.

When changing between landscape and portrait, the `onCreate()` is called over and over again (and I want it that way - need to change layouts), but after few tries the app runs out of memory and crashes.

Those observers are not class members so they live in the scope of `onCreate()`.

Any idea anyone?

(When I comment all registrations, I don't have any crashes).

Comment: unregister it when you've done, register again if you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

after being registered, your observers outlive the onCreate context, since they are referenced in the contentresolver.

You need to unregister your contentObservers before registering new ones.

Comment: To be a little more precise, you should unregister your content observers in onDestroy.

Comment: in this case, not exactly: you can go several times in onCreate before ending in onDestroy. which means that you should make sure that you do only register one observer

Comment: Sorry, you are incorrect. Every onCreate for a single instance of an Activity is always paired with an onDestroy unless the process is destroyed by Android. If that is the case, then your content observers are automatically unregistered. When you rotate the phone, a new instance of the Activity is created (calling onCreate) and the old one is destroyed (calling onDestroy).

Comment: To further support what @JustinBreitfeller said, please take a look at the lifecycle of an activity here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#Fragments  Here you can see there will never be an instance where calls to onCreate outnumber the calls to onDestroy (combined with onStop if Android kills the process).

Comment: When switching screen orientation, or not, if you don't unregister the ContentObserver in the onDestroy method, your application will always leak memory. So it's good practice to always unregister the ContentObserver when it's destroyed.